# What is a better database connection to use for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, adodb

Coding in a vba environment, I'm using the ADODB recordset scheme in inserting rows to my database server. It takes me a lot of time to insert many lines on casual inserting per data. Is there a better or a much quicker way on pushing data to the DB on SQL Server?

Comment: What kind of data at what rate to where? little bit more light on these would be helpful

Comment: Am inserting Sales data. from 1 - 2k lines of rows to an online SQL Server via ADODB.recordset method.

Comment: If you are not using transaction try using transaction. It may speed up your insert significantly. check MSDN [ADO Transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227162(v=vs.60).aspx). Also check your table don't have too many indexes and triggers. Alternatively you can try [bulk Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) depending on from where your data is coming.

Comment: Microsoft recommends linked tables. This takes advantage of DAO.